# Массив или переменные

Tags: php

Как бы вы в социальной сети "оформили" данные о пользователе, сделали бы массив с кучей значениями или же просто много переменных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы массивом оформил все, хотябы из тех побуждений, что в случае надобности передать все эти данные как параметр в функцию или метод удобно указать просто массив данных без перечисления всех составляющих.

Answer (score 1):

Ни первое, ни второе. Класс с кучей свойств и методов.